# Converting javascript object to JSON using stringify

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have gone through the earlier answers suggesting JSON.stringify but it is not working as i expected.. here is the situation:

```
[
 {
 category = 'Telephone & Accessories';
 in_stock = 'True';
 description = '-';
 },
 {
 category = 'Telephone & Accessories';
 in_stock = 'False';
 description = '-';
 }
]
```

I am using JSON.stringify() but it is returning the array as:

```
[
 '{
 "category" = "Telephone & Accessories";
 "in_stock" = "True";
 "description" = "-";
 }',
 '{
 "category" = "Telephone & Accessories";
 "in_stock" = "False";
 "description" = "-";
 }'
]
```

This is not what i expected.. I did not want the entire JSON object to be enclosed in a quotation mark..

anyone faced the same issue?

expected:

```
[
 {
 "category" = "Telephone & Accessories";
 "in_stock" = "True";
 "description" = "-";
 },
 {
 "category" = "Telephone & Accessories";
 "in_stock" = "False";
 "description" = "-";
 }
]
```

Comment: That's what stringify *does*, it turns it into a string, as indicated by the quotes. What exactly *did* you want?!

Comment: This isn't even syntactically valid Javascript to begin with

Comment: @jonrsharpe: but then it is not a valid JSON isnt it? I am trying to upload the result as a json file..

Comment: None of those things are valid JS/JSON, because of the `=`. Please give a [mcve] to illustrate what your actual problem is. But JSON.stringify, as the name suggests, creates a valid JSON string corresponding to its input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like the result you get is from a `map` or `reduce` function.

```
// I changed your value to be a valid json object ('=' -> ':') and (';' -> ',')
var data = [
     {
       category : 'Telephone & Accessories',
       in_stock : 'True',
       description : '-'
     },
     {
       category : 'Telephone & Accessories',
       in_stock : 'False',
       description : '-'
     }
];
data.map(JSON.stringify); // is same result as what you get
```

While if you pass `data` directly to `JSON.stringify`, you should get the valid JSON string.

```
// data was declare above 
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data)
// jsonString is a valid JSON string
```

You problem might be the behavior of `map` function or chaining function of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the syntax here. You've got some errors in your Javascript object.
This it what it should look like:

```
const data = [
  {
    category: 'Telephone & Accessories',
    in_stock: true,
    description: '-'
  },
  {
    category: 'Telephone & Accessories',
    in_stock: false,
    description: '-'
  }
]
```

Notice the differences:

- properties in Javascript objects are separated by comma (,) not semi-colon (;)
- Key-value paires are defined by key: value, not key = value. (colon : instead of equal =)
- true and false (as boolean values) must not be surrounded by quotes.

Nevertheless, JSON.stringify() always encloses the string with quotation marks.

Can you explain and show more of your implementation, please?